# Cannot set selectedValue at the initial state when programmatically declare the combobox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedvalue

I have a problems here, when I create a combo box in the coding I found that I am not able to set the selectedValue immediately after bind with the data source. The coding below is used to help me explain the problem.

I think I already found the problem, the problem might be something due with the synchronous. It means this line of code (comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2) will execute before the combobox datasource is properly bind, so the combobox could not find the data when comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 is executed and generate errors. If I am wrong please correct me.

My solution is putting a while loop immediately after comboBox1.DataSource = data to make sure the combobox is bind properly before it can go to the next line of code. I am sure that this is not a good ways.

**Does any others better solution for this??** Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private ComboBox comboBox1 = new ComboBox();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string[] data = { "a", "b", "c" };

        comboBox1.DataSource = data;

        //This line of code is used to confirm the data source 
        //is bind to the combo box
        while (comboBox1.DataSource == null) ;            

        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

        this.Controls.Add(comboBox1);

        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2;
    }

    void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("");
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be a typo in the sample code, i think you wrote `comboBox2` instead of `comboBox1`

Comment: Haha, typo error, thanks @Benoit Blanchon, I already correct it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the `ComboBox.BindingContext` to a dummy instance.

```
string[] data = { "a", "b", "c" };
comboBox1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
comboBox1.DataSource = data;
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

See [ComboBox.DataSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f.aspx) and [BindingContext Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcontext.aspx)